# how to merge 2 same collections in larave

Tags: php, laravel

consider on first query i get 2 rows and on 2nd query i get 1 row i want to 2+1 = 3 rows into a single collection so that i can have all the data here is my query

```
 $invoices = Invoice::whereIn('user_id', $ids)->get(); //have data in column id 1 and 2
    $stock = Invoice::where('customer_id' , Auth::id())->get(); // have data in column id 3 
    $merge = //how i can merge this?
```

now consider i merged both my output should be using foreach

```
foreach($merge as $a){
$b[] = $a->id;
}
dd($b);
```

**output should be [1,2,3]**

Comment: The [`merge`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge) method is possibly what you're looking for?

Comment: why do you need to merge them, you can get all of this with 1 query

Comment: @Unflux yes somthing like that which can merge rows

Comment: @lagbox i dont want to use Invoices::all() because it is role based

Comment: no one said to use `all`, the word "all" in my statement is referring to all the results you have there ... this is literally 1 query to get this data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the both result in one query using [orWhere](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses):

```
$mergedResult=Invoice::whereIn('user_id', $ids)->orWhere('customer_id' , Auth::id())->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one query, **BUT** if you actually want to merge these 2 Eloquent Collections:

```
$new = $invoices->merge($stock);
```

Surprise, there is a `merge` method.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `merge`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge)